# Two libraries use the same @Autowired class, one with @Qualifier, one without - how to make them work together?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using two libraries, let's call them "*NoQ*" and "*WithQ*" (you'll see why).

Both depend on the same object class, both have classes where they expect Spring to inject this object via `@Autowired`. So far so good. But *NoQ* library uses plain `@Autowired`, no qualifier, and also includes a `@Component` class that implements the bean; *WithQ* uses `@Autowired` `@Qualifier("name")`, and expects me to provide the bean.

When I try to let the `@Component` inject into both libraries, *WithQ* fails because the qualifier isn't present. When I provide my own `@Bean("name")` supplier, then *NoQ* fails because there are two objects that could both satisfy its `@Autowired`. I also tried using XML syntax and `autowired="byName"`, hoping that would force *NoQ* to ignore the second bean, but no luck, I still get the error about two beans on startup.

I can't really change either library. How can I use them both? I'm OK with them sharing the object, or with them each getting their own version of it - either of them is OK. I just want a way to get both of them to start up together in my application.

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` will map the singleton object which is created in spring container. We can tell spring to create the Object by annotating the class with `@Component`. If you have two class and both depends on same class (A) and class (A) is annotated with `@Component` then `@Autowired` will help you to map the object in both NoQ and WithQ.

This is not fixing the issue then could you please share the stacktrace and code so I can help you. 
And also please tag me after you updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to skip the unwanted bean during component scan:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.blah" }, excludeFilters = @Filter({NoQBean1.class}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: I created yet a third object of the class, with no qualifier, then marked it as @Primary. Now the qualified one is found by WithQ, the primary one is used by NoQ, and the one created inside of NoQ is ignored.